# Using Intent.ACTION_PICK for specific path

Tags: android, gallery

I am trying to use Android gallery to pick image. Launching gallery is easy for that purpose

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

However, I need to limit images that are shown in the gallery to specific path on device (i.e. to show images from single folder only). Is this possible to do and how?

Comment: i just answer this quest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074270/built-in-gallery-in-specific-folder/8255674#8255674 may be it help you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sorry, no this is not possible.

Also you are using this Intent protocol wrong. As per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK this protocol expects that you put the content: URI of the data set you want the picker to select from.

That said, you should consider `ACTION_PICK` deprecated.  The modern action is `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` which is much better supported; you will find support of `ACTION_PICK` spotty and inconsistent.  Unfortunately, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` also does not let you specify a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why not ?

```
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(galleryIntent)
```

Good luck with..

Comment: Hello Taha. And welcome to StackOverflow. Remember to consider pointing the user to documentation or reasoning about your answer instead of just pasting code.