# get only specific videos using Android using ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, video

I am developing an app in android. This app create video and save in sdcard. this app also allow user to pick video from gallery and run.
My problem is I want to limit the user to get only from those videos which were created using the app. For this purpose I want to show only those videos, create by app in gellry, when user move to gallery for pick the videos.

i am using the following code to show vidoe gallery.

```
Intent intnt = new Intent();
intnt.setType("video/*");
intnt.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intnt, "Select Video"),1);
```

This code show all videos in video gallery. But I don't know how to show only those video in gallery created using app.

Comment: you can store your app video in separate folder. Create folder in sd card for your application. it's gud way to find out your video.

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486716/using-intent-action-pick-for-specific-path  it looks like it can not be done using the default gallery app... may be you can create your own gallery activity for selection of video from your folder.......

Comment: Agreed to both of you. Thankyou! :)