# Android : How to restrict Google Drive visibilty in file upload?

Tags: android, android-intent, file-upload

I have a concept of file uploading in my application. When I clicks the button file upload then it is showing all the folders available in my device like File Explorer, Gallery etc. It is also showing the Google Drive folder. But I don't want to make it visible.

I don't know how to do that?

Please someone can help me.

This is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select a file to upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
```

Comment: Hey u got the answer ?. I am too facing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe what you want to use is `Intent.ACTION_PICK` instead of `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765265/difference-between-intent-action-get-content-and-intent-action-pick). There you will find the difference between the two of them. Basically, that you should use `Intent.ACTION_PICK` when you want to select files from a particular location and `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` when you do not care about the location but want a specific kind of data.