# Open pictures from a folder in gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I want to open all the pictures from a specific folder using the Android Gallery. I found a solution in an old question but it didn't work. The code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

public String[] allFiles;
private String SCAN_PATH;
private static final String FILE_TYPE = "image/*";
private MediaScannerConnection conn;
private String folderName = "MyAPP";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.album);

    File folder = new File("/sdcard/"+folderName+"/");
    allFiles = folder.list();

    SCAN_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + "/"+folderName+"/" + allFiles[0];

    Button scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startScan();
        }
    });
}

private void startScan() {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this, this);
    conn.connect();
}

public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    conn.scanFile(SCAN_PATH, FILE_TYPE);
}

public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    try {
        if (uri != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
    }
}
}
```

With this code I'm getting this error:

```
08-14 11:09:20.093: W/ContentResolver(25151): Failed to get type for: content://media/external/images/media/10471 (Unknown URL : content://media/external/images/media/10471)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT dat=content://media/external/images/media/10471 }
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at com.example.camtest.MainActivity.onScanCompleted(MainActivity.java:64)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.media.MediaScannerConnection$1.scanCompleted(MediaScannerConnection.java:53)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.media.IMediaScannerListener$Stub.onTransact(IMediaScannerListener.java:60)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
08-14 11:09:20.093: E/JavaBinder(25151):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

It'd be ok if I can get this code works but I can use any other idea you suggest me

Comment: 1. Try with `intent.setType("image/*");` after the declaration of the `Intent`. 2. Read here a little bit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT 3. Declare the activity in the Manifest (check this just in case). 4. What are the types of the images for the Gallery?

Comment: Will you please elaborate your question what means "I want to open all the pictures from a specific folder using the Android Gallery."????

Comment: I want to open a gallery but only with pictures in a folder called MyAPP

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

The code you use above is to open picture in gallery, but not passing a uri to gallery to open it.
If you want to view pictures in a folder by gallery, I introduce you to see [How to open gallery to show images in a specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253301/how-to-open-gallery-to-show-images-in-a-specific-directory) ,hope it will help.

Comment: I think the diference is that you use Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, which should be Intent.ACTION_VIEW.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the actual correct solution:

The secret is finding the bucket/album your folder is represented as.  Buckets show up after a successful MediaScan so be sure any images/videos you want to show are first scanned as demonstrated multiple times above.

Let's assume I have an indexed folder in /sdcard/myapp/**myappsmediafolder**:

```
String bucketId = "";

final String[] projection = new String[] {"DISTINCT " + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + ", " + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};
final Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    final String bucketName = cur.getString((cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)));
    if (bucketName.equals("myappsmediafolder")) {
        bucketId = cur.getString((cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID)));
        break;
    }
}
```

Now that we have the bucketId for our album we can open it with a simple intent.

Filters Video files:

```
Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

Filters Image files:

```
Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

...

```
if (bucketId.length() > 0) {
    mediaUri = mediaUri.buildUpon()
            .authority("media")
            .appendQueryParameter("bucketId", bucketId)
            .build();
}

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mediaUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I can verify this works with the built-in Gallery app.  Mileage may vary with other apps such as Google Photos.

I have yet to figure out how not to filter images/video, even though within Gallery you can select a specific Album with no filter.

I figured this out by looking at the AOSP source to the gallery app.

This questions is also a duplicate of: [Gallery with folder filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019534/gallery-with-folder-filter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on button click

```
 browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent i = new Intent(
             Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

             startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

}
```

});

and you can set this selected image into your application as follows

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

         imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.property_image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

   }}
```

In first block of code i use startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE); this return result to called activity and we can get this result by second block of code, and set selected image in your ImageView

Answer (score 0):

I have retrieved images path from a specific folder and displayed it on recycler View. The code is in Kotlin but you can get a idea from

```
private fun getAllShownImagesPath(): ArrayList<String> {

    var filePath: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
    val path = File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).path, "BacFo Camera")
    if (path.exists()) {

        for (i in path.list().iterator()) {

            filePath?.add("" + path.toString() + "/" + i)
        }
    }

    return filePath!!
}
```

So, now you have list of images path that you can pass on to recycler view using recycler view Adapter. Easy :-)