# Intent ignoring setData

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

Right now I have:

```
Intent gallery = new Intent( ACTION_PICK,
   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );
gallery.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/DCIM/"), "image/*");
startActivity(gallery);
```

What I'd like to accomplish is to only display images from the DCIM directory down, but instead I'm seeing every image on the device.  I don't see any errors or warnings popping up for my process when I run this.  I've tried splitting into setData and setType which predictably had the same effect.

Thanks in advance for any insight into what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer by [PiyushMishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510617/piyushmishra)

[Built-in gallery in specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074270/built-in-gallery-in-specific-folder/8255674#8255674)