# How to open Gallery and select whole album(folder) from android app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106486/android-launch-gallery-folder-and-select-image) and [this very good article](http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/) on how to open gallery app with an intent, let user choose a photo, and get a reference to the chosen photo in my own app.

I want that the user may be able to choose an album (a folder) on the gallery instead of a photo.

Is this possible with an intent? If yes, how? If not, what can I do?

Comment: what have you tried so far? What's your findings saying?

Comment: Yes you can request a list of all albums first and let the user choose one to open.

Comment: I've tried doing this another way. I made my own activities for browsing through the device storage, and selecting and returning folders. This works, but I have written the entire gallery logic again (about navigation through folders).
I was hoping that there is a more direct way of doing this.

Comment: @greenapps yes, that is how I have done. But isn't there a way to open the actual gallery app and get it done? One downside of this method is that you won't see the attractive gallery UI, unless you clone it in your app.

Comment: Then your subject is not to the point. It seems that you want to open the Gallery app displaying a specific folder. Does not have much to do with selecting. Would you really let the user select a folder if possible?