# Open a specific folder inside gallery android

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

I have a camera app which save image to separate folder inside the gallery. 
Path to my folder is   `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraExample/`

When I click on the button I need to open the folder where I have saved the images. I have used all the solution which was available.

This how I'm reading the path. Let me know if i'm wrong.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("HelperUtils . getFilePaths", "setting the path " + path);
        String targetPath = path +"/CameraExample/";
```

How to start a new Intent and open the files?

Comment: You did not tell how you open the Gallery app without indicating a specific folder. The gallery is no storage place as you suggest. It's only an app that can show all images on your device.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019534/gallery-with-folder-filter

Answer (score 4):

You can list all files which exist in your directory like this

```
File[] listFile;
File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraExample");
if (file.isDirectory()) 
        listFile = file.listFiles();
```

Then you can display those images using `GridView` or however you want.

**EDIT:**
To open your folder using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()
+ "/CameraExample/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Comment: This is ok. But I need to open myfolder from built-in gallery. I don't want to create any gridview, bcoz android gallery handles everything. I just need to open myfolder.

Comment: For that you need to create a MediaScanner, to let the gallery know what to show. The gallery will not show any images, even if they are in the same folder, unless they are explicitly added to the gallery.

Comment: Can you provide me a example on implementing MediaScanner. If is just implement MediaScanner , is that enough or should I have to do addition work in XML layout file.

Comment: Above code is opening the recent images of gallery not the images from the specific folder. Example on implementing the media scanner?

Comment: Cross check pictures in opend folder and cameraexample folder.. Should be same