# How to open DCIM/Camera folder in default Files app from intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent, camera, gallery

I am making a camera app which takes both front camera and back camera images/video and I do not want individual thumbnails on the Camera preview for each file.

I want to open "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera" folder using the Files app and further open the photo/video which is not possible with ACTION_GET_CONTENT as it selects the image and exits the Files app as tried here -

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).path.toString() + "/Camera")
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"))
```

I tried ACTION_VIEW too, but it is not specific to one folder and opens the gallery showing all media as tried here -

```
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    startActivity(intent)
```

"image/*" shows images and videos too in the gallery for me which is good. When "*/*" is used we can use the Files app too but it opens the downloads folder.
One solution I found works only with ES Explorer as tried here -

```
    val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).path.toString() + "/Camera")
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder")
    startActivity(intent)
```

This is due to "resource/folder" not supported leading to a crash. Changing "resource/folder" to "*/*" makes Files app open the downloads folder and Photos app to hang.

It seems gallery can do it via [buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35397245/10183099), but it too is not universal.

I am not asking for much, just to display my Camera folder from where I can open and view any photo/video.

Comment: I am willing to add a bounty on this question but cannot find the option.

Comment: We wait until you found the option and we know the bounty ;-).

Comment: I found that I can add a bounty after 2 days but the minimum reputation is 50. https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty. I guess I need to spend more time here for that!

Comment: Yes, you could spend some time here reading some stackoverflow pages tagged 'android' as what you want has been asked before.

Comment: But.. You can let the picker open in the same folder as where the user picked a file before. If you put the obtained content scheme uri in an extra for the next intent then it works. Google for INITIAL_URI.

Comment: I have read replies to similar questions but they are not applicable for my usecase. I think you mean https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI. It is applicable only to Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
Intent#ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT
Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE but I do not want to pick anything. I want to open like Files app or Gallery normally would.

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible if the user had not once selected a file using ACTION_GET_CONTENT was the opinion.

But now... try this code:

```
String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3APictures";
//  String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(scheme);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri); // Added in API level 26 

startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);

Toast.makeText(context, "Picker opened in:\n\n" + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It works here and i'm pretty amazed.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem as I can only view the thumbnails and if I click them, they get selected and returned, rather than opening. That's the problem with ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: Of course. Thats how it is with ACTION_GET_CONTENT. It is for picking files. Has nothing to do with opening in a certain folder. Normal behaviour.  I think it was unclear to me what you wanted.

Comment: I just want the Files app to open in the DCIM/Camera folder

Comment: Well try this with action_view and report.

Comment: On lot of devices there is no Files app to begin with.

Comment: I have described that behaviour in my question, it does not open a specific folder. Files app just opens the downloads folder and Photos app hangs

Comment: There is some Files viewer in all of my relevant devices but not ES Explorer. If the default Files or Gallery can open the folder it is good.

Answer (score 0):

To open the Files app starting with a certain folder you can use below code but only for Android 11 devices sadly.

```
//String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3APictures";
//String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload";
//String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/10F9-2E19%3ADownload";
String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(scheme);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.android.document/root"); 

startActivity(intent );

Toast.makeText(context, "Files app opening in:\n\n" + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: It's good that they added this in Android 11, unfortunately, my app is Android 10 based.

Comment: It is not the compile version of your app. Its the Android version of the used device.

Comment: The target device has Android 10 and I cannot change it.