# Android: Can I specify DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS as starting point for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent?

Tags: android, android-11

The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent which lets the user pick a file to be opened by my app can get pointed to some URI where it would list files from.

Is there some Android 11 compatible way to point this to DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS?

Or which allowed ways exist on Android 11 to store my own binary format files outside the application and have read/write access to?

Or put otherwise: what comes closest to Windows Application File/Open which is not restricted to an app internal location only and where I can specify which files to list by extension as my own binary format won't match any existing MIME types.

And where to get a list of the "standard" MIME types usually present on each Android device (at least "Google certified" ones)?

Comment: Sorry: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent is meant.

Comment: I corrected it now. And what's the answer now? Does a solution for my problem exist?

Comment: You have two questions in your post which are not related. Very confusing. You better had made two posts.

Comment: Try if you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454993/how-to-open-dcim-camera-folder-in-default-files-app-from-intent/65456499?noredirect=1#comment115724034_65456499